# Need help to INSERT data from array as input parameter using Postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

can any one help to create function in postgresql where parameters are `insertdatausingarray(exp_ids array, group_id integer)` and inside function that to iterate the array (exp_ids)
do insertion accordingly

**Data**
exp_ids as array i.e. {3275, 3845, 3578, 3125}  and  group_id 1000520 - common for all

insertdatausingarray({3275, 3845, 3578, 3125}, 1000520)

**Table:**
Here, staructre is this
group_id | exp_id
and data looks as below:

```
exp_id, group_id
    3275,   1000520
    3845,   1000520
    3578,   1000520
    3125,   1000520
```

let me know if any further clarification required

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function to do this, although you could put the SQL in a function if you really wanted to.  You just need to unnest the array.  In this example, I'm using a WITH clause to pass in the data, but you could obviously do this some other way, like from your application.

```
WITH data(exp_ids, group_id) AS (
  VALUES ('{3275, 3845, 3578, 3125}'::int[], 1000520)
)
INSERT INTO test (exp_id, group_id)
SELECT unnest(exp_ids), group_id
FROM data;
```

If you really need a function, it's just the main part of the query wrapped in a function:

````
CREATE FUNCTION my_function(p_exp_ids int[], p_group_id int) RETURNS void AS $$
    INSERT INTO test (exp_id, group_id)
    SELECT unnest(p_exp_ids), p_group_id
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;```
````

Comment: Thanks Jeremy but i need function to integrate on application by calling so could you please help me on the same

Comment: Okay, I added the function, but it's really just the same query, wrapped in a function.